# return RedirectToAction to a Index but with a href sections? (Ajax optional)

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have multiple sections in a single View file, for example, `href="#timeline"` for  `<div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">`. `href="#settings"` for `<div class="tab-pane" id="settings">`

Clicking the tab Timeline will bring you to the tab that shows you a timeline.
Clicking the tab Settings will bring you to the tab that allows you change settings.

How do I return view in the Controlller to a section href="#settings" in the same View file?

Thanks.

Models:

```
 public class UserViewModel
    {
        public List<Timeline> TheTimeline { get; set; }
        public List<Posts> ThePosts{ get; set; }
        public string SettingsVM{ get; set; }
    }
```

Controllers:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SettingsUpdateProfile(User variable, IFormFile TheEmployeePicture)
        {
          blablabla
                    if (UploadFile(TheEmployeePicture, fname))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(String.Format("Index/{0}", User.Identity.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return BadRequest();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Views:

```
@model UserProfile.Models.UserViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UUUSSSEEERRR";
}

<div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                              <li class="active"><a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab">Posts</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">Timeline</a></li>


<div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">
                          ...
                        </div>
```

Comment: How about partial view? and use ajax helper to bind that?

Comment: Why not to use ajax?

Comment: Can you share my your ajax solution?

Comment: Please share your model and current html

Comment: There you go Just Code

Answer (score 0):

If you use same ViewModel for both tabs, i recomend don't use ajax, as you don't need more request, if you have enougth data for display.

```
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs in" id="your_id">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#timeline">Time Line</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">Time Line</a></li>
       </ul>
     <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", Model)}</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">@{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { routeParams})}</div>
    </div>
```

So you can choose, use render partial and pass model as param and view name or you can Render Action, it will do request and return view.

Comment: I have the same ViewModel unfortunately. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: so what a problem ? Use Html.RenderPartial("VIEWNAME",Model.SettingsVM). It will siple return formatted html according your view?